# Behaviour of a rational function in the vicinity of a pole

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions

I find hard to prove the following result : if $F=\frac PQ$ is a rational function, and if $a$ is a pole of $F$ of order $\alpha$, then there are reals $M>0$ and $\nu>0$ such that for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$ verifying $\left|t\right|>M$, equation $F(z)=t$ has exactly $\alpha$ zeros in the disc $B(a,\nu)=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}, \left|z-a\right|<\nu\right\}$.

I tried this : let $Q=(X-a)^\alpha Q_1$, with $Q_1(a)\ne0$, the equation $F(z)=t$ can be written
$$P(z)-t(z-a)^\alpha Q_1(z)=0 \iff (z-a)^\alpha = \frac1t \frac{P(z)}{Q_1(z)}$$
$\frac{P(a)}{Q_1(a)}\ne0$, so fraction $\frac{P}{Q_1}$ doesn't cancel in the vicinity of $a$. The equation looks "just like" equation
$$(z-a)^\alpha = \frac1t \frac{P(a)}{Q_1(a)}$$
which clearly has exactly $\alpha$ solutions for $t$ sufficiently large (so $M$ has to be fixed AFTER $\nu$), but I don't know how to translate this to the actual equation.

A tip, anyone ?

Thanks.

Comment: Since both are $\exists$ clauses that are together, there is no issue with picking $M$ after $\nu$. But I am perplexed by your question. You started off by showing that the "actual equation" is equivalent to the final equation, where you deduced that there are exactly $\alpha$ solutions. What more "translation" are you looking for?

Comment: What I mean by "fixing M AFTER nu" is that M seems to be dependent of nu in the proof. And the second equation is not equivalent to the one I want to solve, just that as P(z)/Q(z) doesn't change a lot near a, the equation is "almost like" the one with a constant. And "almost" is not enough to conclude.

Comment: I think there could be an argument about the roots of the polynomial $P(z)-t(z-a)^\alpha Q_1(z)$ : it has at least as many roots as its degree, which is greater than $\alpha$, but one could show that in the vicinity of $a$, there are only $\alpha$ roots. But I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: And what I mean by "there is no issue" is that it doesn't matter that the $M$ you pick depends on the $\nu$ you pick. You only need to find one value of $\nu$ and one value of $M$ for which the whole thing works. Picking $\nu$ fiirst, then using it to pick an $M$ still gives you a value of each that works. But on the second point, I had failed to notice that in the final equation, $P$ and $Q_1$ are evaluated at $a$, not $z$. You are correct that this is insufficient by itself to prove the result.

Comment: I understand your explanation, I don't care if $M$ and $\nu$ are independent or not. It wasn't the central point of my development, just a thought passing by ;-)